# Product of a series and asequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

Suppose $\{a_n\}_{n \in N} $ be a  bounded sequence  positive numberse bounded by $b$ and $Z_j,j=1,2,3,...$ be a sequnce of complex random variables such that $E(|z_j|)<\frac{1}{\sqrt{(j+1)m}}$ for some paramter $m \in N $.What can we conclude  about the expectation of $$\Bigg| \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_jZ_j \Bigg|$$ as $m$ also approaches infinity?  
**My attempt so far.**
$$E\left(\Bigg |\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_jZ_j \Bigg| \right) \leq \left( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}E\Bigg |a_jZ_j \Bigg| \right) \leq  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_jE \bigg( \Big |Z_j \Big| \bigg) \leq b \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(j+1)m}} .$$
I don't know how to procedd further as we take the limit $m \rightarrow \infty$. I would be hihly obliged for any hints\responces

Comment: This bound is correct but useless because it's infinite: the right hand sum diverges.  Consider a simple case of your question: $a_n=1$ for all $n$ and $Z_j= (j+1)^{-1/2}$ for all $j.$  The sum of the $a_j Z_j$ has a divergent expectation.

Comment: U have not taken m into account

Comment: Seriously? Let $m=1.$